# array_unshift command doesn't work properly in yii2

Tags: yii2

I have a problem here. I have a drop-down list with a users and when I click on any user, it shows a clients which are assigned to it.

Now I've added `Unassigned clients` selection into the drop-down top to show which clients are unassigned. I've added it with a `array_unshift()` command, but now in some existing users (not all of it) it's not showing any clients, but these are assigned in the database.

When I remove `array_unshift`, the clients shows properly, but then there are no extra selection.

I'm thinking that there are something wrong with the `array_unshift()`, but not sure..

Here is my select function:

```
public static function getUsers()
{
    $query = self::find()
        ->select(['id', "CONCAT(name, ' ', surname, ' (', email, ')') as name"]);

    $users = ArrayHelper::map($query->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name');

    array_unshift($users, 'Test'));

    return $users;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php):

> All numerical array keys will be modified to start counting from zero while literal keys won't be changed.

Use `+`:

```
public static function getUnmappedUsersList()
{
    $query = self::find()
        ->select(['id', "CONCAT(name, ' ', surname, ' (', email, ')') as name"]);

    return [Yii::t('app', 'ADMIN_PANEL_MIGRATE_UNASSIGNED_CLIENTS')] 
        + ArrayHelper::map($query->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name');
}
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. Could you also please explain the sentence you've written about all numerical keys...? I can't get it. I'm trying to `var_dump()` mine `array_unshift` and your return, but the result gives me exact same array. So what is different?

Comment: It can not be the same array. `ArrayHelper::map` generates something like `['12' => 'aaa', '34' => 'bbb', '36' => 'ccc']` when you use `array_unshift` it is being remapped to `[0 => 'unshifted element', 1 => 'aaa', 2 => 'bbb', 3 => 'ccc']`.